# Auth0 : Multistep signup form for paid users

Tags: auth0

I am using auth0 in my existing regular php web application.
I have free as well as paid users in my site. For free users registration process is simple, I call the create user api which triggers the verification email.

But for paid users I have a multistep form. In first step users enters his information and registered as a free user in application then redirected to payment page. I can not call auth0 reg api after first step as user will get immediately verification email before payment.

If I call it after successful payment then its impossible to track if user bails out(Doesn't fill payment form, but already registered as a free user).
Please suggest what approach I should follow.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you disabled public signups ([this endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#authenticate-user)) and instead are performing the registration of users from your backend through the Management API [create user endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/post_users).

Then you can use the `verify_email` parameter to indicate that a verification email should not immediately be send after user creation. You could then later use [this endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Jobs/post_verification_email) to trigger a verification email to be sent after the payment form is completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have want to achieve best result i think you must follow below step to get rid of this problem:
1. Remove public signups in your application by trying this  [authenticating signup](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#signup).

2.Perform the registration of individual user by this way [create user's](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/post_users)

3.Now you can simply  use the **verify_email** parameter.

This parameter can be easily use [post verification email process](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Jobs/post_verification_email) which prevent the issue of signup/signin before making payment.
Hope you got it & feel free for any help.